# How to make a delay in assembly for 8051 microcontrollers?

Tags: 8051

I am having a problem in calculating delays. I want to make a delay for 0.5 sec when I am using 1MHz clock speed for my 8051 microcontroller.

I use proteus for simulation and avr studio for coding in assembly for atmel microcontroller.

For example this code is for 8MHz clock microcontroller

```
Delay_15mS:
LDI dly1,  120  ; 
Delay1:
    LDI  dly2, 250  ;
Delay2:
    DEC     dly2 ; 
    NOP  ; 
    BRNE   Delay2  ; 

    DEC   dly1 ;
    BRNE    Delay1  ; 
RET
```

Can you teach me how to calculate the time this delay will take? So I could make 1 for 0.5 sec delay @ 1 MHz

Thank you

Comment: The first answer in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5134836/writing-a-delay-subroutine) may help. If you would like more information, try [searching](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[8051]+delay).

Answer (score 0):

0,5 s is an eternity in the life of (even slow) microcontroller.

Do you realize that you will not be able to do anything while waiting like this ?  ( called passive wait )

Phil Wetzel gave you in its comment a link to a post describing interrupts. That's what you need.

It would however require to read the datasheet to know how to configure the clocking system, how to configure a timer, how to set and write the interrupt for this timer...

However to answer your question ( if your code snippet is correct (?) ):
For a 15 ms timeout on a 8 MHz system you would realize 120 times a second loop (delay2).

So now you have a 8 times slower system but you want to wait 0.5/0.015 = 33.33... times more.

So you would wait for 120 / 8 * 0.5 / 0.015 = 500 delay1 loops

But as your µC is a 8 bit one, you can not store such a value in a 8 bits register.

So I fear what you are asking is impossible ( unless you write the code to handle a 16 bits variable ). You may also create a delay0 loop and wait 2 times 250 delay1 loops.

Not sure what accuracy you will get !!